# Find content in file and replace all the line

Tags: c#, string, file, search

I have a file that contains smth like this:

```
Elsa 12 15
Charlie 3 60
Mattew 4 0
```

I need to find string, that starts with name and then replace all it line with changed values. I dont know values before search.

So for example I know, that I need to add Mattew +2 to his first value and +4 to second, then file will be like this:

```
Elsa 12 15
Charlie 3 60
Mattew 6 4
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have  you tried? what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate each line of your file using `for` loop and find needed one with `string.StartsWith()` method. Then, if needed line was found - just rewrite it with provided `nameToFind` and new integer values `newValue1` and `newValue2`, combining them with `string.Join()` and `" "` whitespace separator.

Example, if you want to set new values to both numbers at line.

```
static void EditValues(string nameToFind, int newValue1, int newValue2)
{
    string file = @"S:\File.txt";

    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            if (lines[i].StartsWith(nameToFind))
            {    
                // Just rewrite line with same name but new values
                lines[i] = string.Join(" ", nameToFind, newValue1, newValue2);

                // Optionally, if there is no more values to edit - you can break loop immediately
                break;
            }

        // Save (write) lines array back to file.
        File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
    }
}
```

Simplified version with founding index of line with `Array.FindIndex`. Note, that if in file is few "Mattew"s - only first would be edited in that case.

```
static void EditValues(string nameToFind, int newValue1, int newValue2)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("File.txt");
    int index = Array.FindIndex(lines, line => line.StartsWith(nameToFind));
    lines[index] = string.Join(" ", nameToFind, newValue1, newValue2);
    File.WriteAllLines("File.txt", lines);
}
```

If you need to set only one of two numbers in line, you can use some kind of `bool` flag (`editFirstNumber` in example below) to define first or second number in line should be edited.
To get both numbers you can split line by `" "` whitespace separator using `string.Split()` method.

Example for editing only one of two numbers:

```
static void EditValue(string nameToFind, int newValue, bool editFirstNumber)
{
    string file = @"S:\File.txt";

    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            if (lines[i].StartsWith(nameToFind))
            {
                string[] lineValues = lines[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 3, StringSplitOptions.None);

                // Parse numbers from line
                int.TryParse(lineValues[1], out int number1); // First number
                int.TryParse(lineValues[2], out int number2); // Second number

                // By boolean flag you can manipulate which one of two numbers to edit
                if (editFirstNumber)
                    number1 = newValue;
                else
                    number2 = newValue;

                lines[i] = string.Join(" ", nameToFind, number1, number2);

                // Optionally, if there is no more values to edit - you can break loop immediatly
                break;
            }

        File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
    }
}
```

Then you can just call `EditValues("Mattew", 6, 4);` where specify name you want to find and new values for first and second integers. Or call `EditValue("Mattew", 6, true);` to edit only first number in line and `EditValues("Mattew", 4, false);` to edit second number in line.

If you can't be sure that each line matches "String Number1 Number2" scheme, you can add some check before parsing to `int` (such as `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineValues[1])`) or use `int.TryParse(lineValues[1], out int currentValue1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to read the file into a Line class (name,firtvalue,secondValue) List    , work with it, and after write it again in a file
List Lines = new List();

```
        contentFile.Split("\n").ToList().ForEach(line =>
        {
           string[] Values = line.Split(" ").ToArray();

            Lines.Add(new Line { Name = Values[0], FirstValue = int.Parse(Values[1]), SecondValue = int.Parse(Values[2]) });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for find and replace row in file

```
public static bool lineChanger(string fileName, string name, int first_num, int sec_num)
{
        //check for exist file
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            return false;

        //find
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList();
        int index = lines.FindIndex(x => x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf(" ")).ToLower() == name.ToLower());
        if (index == -1)
            return false;

        //edit line
        var record = lines[index].Split(" ");
        lines[index] = $"{record[0]} {Convert.ToInt32(record[1]) + first_num} {Convert.ToInt32(record[2]) + sec_num}";
        File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
        return true;
}
```